# delete a cert from a truststore when the alias has unusual characters (?)

Tags: keytool

Using keytool from the command-line, I added a new cert to a store.  But the anger-inducing window manager that I find myself currently stuck with manages to fail at cut-and-paste, and replaced one of the characters of the alias with a ? character.  How do I change or delete that alias?

```
keytool -list -keystore truststore
Enter keystore password:  

Keystore type: JKS
Keystore provider: SUN

Your keystore contains 4 entries

hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1?, Dec 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,
```

.....

```
keytool -delete -keystore truststore -alias 'hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1?'
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1?> does not exist
```

.....

```
keytool -delete -keystore truststore -alias 'hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1\?'
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1\?> does not exist
```

.....

```
keytool -delete -keystore truststore -alias 'hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1'
Enter keystore password:  
keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Alias <hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1> does not exist
```

Thanks for any assistance,

```
 - rob.
```

Comment: Just speculating, but 
```Your keystore contains 4 entries
hail.ucc.nau.edu:8636-cert-1?, Dec 1, 2017, trustedCertEntry,``` 

Perhaps the '?' you see is not actual ?, but something else which your terminal outputs as '?' 

Since this store only has 4 aliases, I'd save myself hair pulling, export the other 3 into another store and then recreate the rogue one with the correct name, then get rid of this.

Answer (score 2):

The special character you are seeing, may not be that actual character as suggested by @Pavel Lechev in the comment. If the `keytool` delete doesn't work, you can use the [KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.org) software to do it. It has nice GUI providing all the keytool functionalities.

Or you could write a small tool/class using `KeyStore` api to delete your unwanted alias. You could list out all the aliases, identify it, and delete it (to identify the alias, you could do `startsWith()`).